# Checkout stuck with loader: Cannot read property 'indexedOptions' of undefined

Tags: checkout, uicomponent, magento-2.1.10

I had to customize the country field in checkout shipping address field.

I edited the checkout_index_index.xml with the new component/template for country field like this

```
 ....
<item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/form/element/country</item>
     <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/form/element/input-country</item>
     </item>
  </item>
</item>
......
```

Everything is working, field is updated with customizations but several times when I arrive at checkout for the first time I get this js error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexedOptions' of undefined (region.js:59)

and chekout is stuck with a loader. I found some documentation about this error which seems to be related to fields removal in checkout, but I didn't remove any field, only updated.

I'm using Magento 2.1.10

Comment: Have you found any solutions for this issue? Plz share if you found

Comment: Hi @Jimit the issue was connected to the extension we used for shipping methods that had several bugs. We moved to another one and the problem was solved